# Resize of SDI frame

Tags: mfc

I want to resize the frame window in a SDI application to a given dimension of the child view window (I want the frame to fit the dimensions of an image). Can anyone describe an (elegant) solution to finding the relation between the child view client size and the frame window size without actually resizing the window?

Currently I am using GetParentFrame()->MoveWindow(,,,) to resize the frame window. I already tried to observe the difference between GetParentWindow()->GetClientRect() and GetParentWindow()->GetWindowRect() but it does not help.

Comment: If you do a `ClientToScreen` on the results of `GetClientRect` does that help?

Comment: The problem was that I had to take into account the scroll bars.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [CWnd::CalcWindowRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bc708350%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It computes the size of the window required to hold a given client area. I've never used it so I don't know how it deals with toolbars, etc. but I think it can be a good starting point.

Comment: Yes this is a good hint. I tried to use it but it does not work in the sense that I think it does not account for some things. However I found some ideas on the net starting from your hint and I will try them.